# Windows: How to check from client the files opened on a network folder

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing, smb

I have a program that has to connect to a folder shared from a server, and I need to know which files and subfolders it is trying to open.

Using `net use` only displays the root of the network folder, not the files opened afaik.

I don't have admin rights on the server, so using `fsmgmt.msc` from the server is not possible.

Is there a way to check it from the client?

Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need Auditing enabled on the server to get this information

Comment: You might test if Nirsoft's Opened Files View, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html , shows which files are being opened over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sysinternals Process Monitor will show you.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

You'll need to add a filter to only show log entries for the specific program that you are interested in.

Admin rights are required on Client, but not the server.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks.